# Select All input control with JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have loaded a report designed with iReport into JasperServer and added the necessary input controls.  I am wondering if there is a way to get a select all check box (or option) for a multi-select input control.  It may be worth mentioning that the control is working fine this is more related to ease-of-use.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's a known enhancement request.

It should be noted that it's possible select the "null" value in the multi-select list. This gets translated to a SQL clause of `1=1` (no filtering) if you linked the multi-select list to the $X syntax. So that's the same result... but for a UI standpoint it's a far cry from an explicit choice of "Select All". Sorry.

Comment: That will actually work for this report, I just needed to remove the 'mandatory' check from the multi-select input control.